# c# webbrowser google translator click listen button

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to click on listen button on google translate using webBrowser control.

```
<div id="gt-src-listen" class="trans-listen-button goog-toolbar-button" data-tooltip="Listen" aria-label="Listen" data-tooltip-align="t,c" aria-pressed="false" role="button" aria-hidden="false" style="user-select: none;" tabindex="0">
<span class="jfk-button-img"></span></div>
```

and I'm trying this but it doesn't work

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("jfk-button-img") == "span")
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you wait for the web page to finish loading?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute of html element is class and should be searched like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/72495/How-to-get-class-attribute-of-an-HTML-element-in-C).

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("classname") == "jfk-button-img")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```